# GRASS GIS 8.2 fails on startup

Tags: grass-gis

I just installed GRASS GIS 8.2.0 with the standalone installer, but I'm having issues at startup. Instead of reaching the main window I end up with the command window shown below.

Any ideas on what the issue might be and how to fix it?

I'm on Windows 11 Pro if that helps.

```
Starting GRASS GIS...
WARNING: Concurrent mapset locking is not supported on Windows
Cleaning up temporary files...

          __________  ___   __________    _______________
         / ____/ __ \/   | / ___/ ___/   / ____/  _/ ___/
        / / __/ /_/ / /| | \__ \\_  \   / / __ / / \__ \
       / /_/ / _, _/ ___ |___/ /__/ /  / /_/ // / ___/ /
       \____/_/ |_/_/  |_/____/____/   \____/___//____/

Welcome to GRASS GIS 8.2.0
GRASS GIS homepage:                      https://grass.osgeo.org
This version running through:            Command Prompt (C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe)
Help is available with the command:      g.manual -i
See the licence terms with:              g.version -c
See citation options with:               g.version -x
If required, restart the GUI with:       g.gui wxpython
When ready to quit enter:                exit

Launching <wxpython> GUI in the background, please wait...
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.1219]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. Med ensamrätt.

C:\Users\kaj.norberg>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS 8.2\Python39\lib\site-packages\wx\core.py", line 3407, in <lambda>
    lambda event: event.callable(*event.args, **event.kw) )
  File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS 8.2\gui\wxpython\wxgui.py", line 95, in show_main_gui
    mainframe = GMFrame(parent=None, id=wx.ID_ANY, workspace=self.workspaceFile)
  File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS 8.2\gui\wxpython\lmgr\frame.py", line 156, in __init__
    self.statusbar = SbMain(parent=self, giface=self._giface)
  File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS 8.2\gui\wxpython\lmgr\statusbar.py", line 38, in __init__
    self.mask = SbMask(self.widget, self.giface)
  File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS 8.2\gui\wxpython\lmgr\statusbar.py", line 87, in __init__
    self.Refresh()
  File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS 8.2\gui\wxpython\lmgr\statusbar.py", line 120, in Refresh
    if gs.find_file(
KeyError: 'name'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue, reported in https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/issues/2497. Unfortunately no fix for this yet.
You could try a bit older version. https://grass.osgeo.org/grass80/binary/mswindows/native/WinGRASS-8.0.2-1-Setup.exe